# ASP.NET Page with ReportViewer Gives the Error below

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, reportviewer

I am having this error when I opening page with Reportviewer, and ideas

Server Error in '/' Application.
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender.set_CultureName(String value) +708
   AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +326
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +985
```

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: locale you mean language of dev. is VB.NE. The things is I cant step through anything once I click the view report button i get the error sometimes when, open a form with reportviewer I get the error. I know that in AsP,NET I use the AJAX Script manager but I can't tell where the error is coming from

Comment: You can set a breakpoint to Page.Load in any aspx code-behind and check  System.Globalization CultureInfo.CurrentCulture object.